# Magento 2 : IE 11 Error "Expected identifier" on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, magento2.2.6

On the **Magento 2.2.6** checkout page, there is a javascript error in IE 11. The error is coming from the default.js file.

*Note : its working fine on all other browsers except IE11.*

**JavaScript Console: showing the error "Expected identifier"**

Comment: Working fine after answer

Comment: Issue only with IE 11 device only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is coming from Amazon payment gateway if enable on checkout. The error is coming from the amazonlogin.js. which is located in following path :

> /vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/amazonlogin.js

In your JS please do following changes

Currently

```
function ($,
    Component,
    ko,
    amazonStorage,
    storage,
    amazonPaymentConfig,
    registry,
    loginButton,
) {
```

Suggested Fix

```
function ($,
    Component,
    ko,
    amazonStorage,
    storage,
    amazonPaymentConfig,
    registry,
    loginButton
) {
```

Please remove "," after loginButton. please apply changes and let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your ans, let me check with your solution.

Comment: Its working fine for me

Comment: Thanks :) Appreciated :)